# How to dynamically set values of a component and test them

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have created a `register` component using `react-bootstrap`. It has `email`, `password` and `submit button` fields in a form. At the end, it has an `Alert` component which should not be visible initially but should show success/failure once the form has been submitted

```
import React from 'react';
import {Col, Row, Container, Card,Button, Alert} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import { useState } from 'react';
import User from '../models/user';

let Register = () => {

    let [state,setState] = useState(new User('',''));

    let submitresponse='';
    let alertvariant='';

    let updateInput = (e) =>{
        setState({
                ...state, //state defined above in useState call. Expand the current state and then override the propoerty which target represents
                [e.target.name] : e.target.value
        })
    }

    let register = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(`registerclick: ${JSON.stringify(state)}`)

        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_REGISTER_USER_URL,{
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(state)
            }) //move to separate funcion in separate file to make it easy to test and reuse?
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(`got response: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
                return res.json();  //return json from res
            })
            .then((data) => { //data is the json returned previously. Promise chaining
                console.log(`data after register user request: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);  
                if(data.result == "success") {
                    setState(new User(data.user,data.email)) //override previous value of data object with value of received json object. 
                    this.submitresponse = "User Registered"
                } else {
                    setState(new User('','')) //override previous value of data object with value of received json object. 
                    this.submitresponse = "User Couldn't be Registered"
                }     
            });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Container className='mt-3'>
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={3}>
                        <Card className="shadow-lg">
                            <Card.Header className='p-3'>
                                 Register
                            </Card.Header>
                            <Card.Body>
                                <Form>
                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                                        <Form.Control name="email" onChange={updateInput} type="text" placeholder="email" aria-label="aria-email" />
                                    </Form.Group>
                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3">    
                                        <Form.Control name="password" onChange={updateInput} type="password" placeholder="password" aria-label="aria-password" />
                                    </Form.Group>                                    
                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3">    
                                        <Button onClick={register} type="submit" name="submit-button" aria-label="aria-submit">Register Button</Button>
                                    </Form.Group>
                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3">    
                                        <Alert name="submit-response-alert" key={this.alertvariant} variant={this.alertvariant} >{this.submitresponse}</Alert>
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Form>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
            
        </>
    )
}

export default Register;
```

How could I

1. Hide the `Alert` initially? What is the way to dynamically set `display:none` for example
2. Make it visible when server response is received?

In the tests, I want to test

1. `Alert` shouldn't be in document initially

   it('Should not show Alert field', async () => {
   render();
   expect(screen.getByName("submit-response-alert")).not.toBeInTheDocument(); //Is this the right way?
   });
2. Once server response is received (mocked), `Alert` should be visible with right message

   it('Should successfully submit the form', async () => {
   const { getByText } = render();

   ```
    await act(async () => {
      fireEvent.click(getByText("Register Button"))
    })  
    expect(screen.getByName("submit-response-alert")).toBeInTheDocument();
   ```

   //how to test that the Alert has the right message
   });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set a state that tracks the progress of the request You can also add a message to it.

```
const [requestState , setRequestState] = useState({completed:false , message:""})
```

add this condition into jsx

```
{requestState.completed && <Alert name="submit-response-alert" key={this.alertvariant} variant={this.alertvariant} >{this.submitresponse}</Alert>}
```

Comment: I am already using a `state` in the component. I suppose I can't use multiple states. So I shoudl be creating a single object for `state` which encapsulates all the things I want in the state?

Comment: Is `{completed...}` the right way to access state? I defined the state as `    let [state,setState] = useState({user: new User('',''),registrationsubmitted:false , registrationresultmessage:""});` and tried to use it `<Form.Group className="mb-3">   {registrationsubmitted && <Alert name="submit-response-alert" key={this.alertvariant} variant={this.alertvariant}>{this.registrationresultmessage}</Alert>} </Form.Group>`
` but got error `ReferenceError: registrationsubmitted is not defined `

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in accessing the variable. I have updated the code.